# Reading CSV from assets then Insert Data into SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I want to insert data of CSV file from assets folder in SQLite in android.
How do I accomplish the task effectively and efficiently?

Comment: Whats your contribution in this share it

Answer (score 2):

use FireFox Browser and install [SQLITE-MANAGER plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

follow few steps.

1.create new database with appropriate name

2.Goto>file> select import

3.now Goto select file navigate to your csv file and select that file

4.select first raw as column name if you set in csv.

5.create it. now save this file ad DB and use it in your project

6.you file this kind of window.

[image]

or you can do it programmatically

follow  this [link](http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/05/how-to-import-csv-configuration-file-to-devices-sqlite-db.html)